# In python, what is character encoding information for?

Tags: python, character-encoding

If you go to https://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/character-encoding.htm you will find the following description of character encoding:

`Character encoding tells the browser and validator what set of characters to use when converting the bits to characters.`

That's all fine and good - but if we were talking about python instead of html, what would we replace `browser and validator` with? How would you define those replacement words?

Comment: Not sure about specific term. I would say - parts of Python responsible for representing textual data. Basically, these parts are encoding/decoding methods. See, https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html.

Answer (score 0):

"Browser" and "validator" are just two types of readers of HTML. They have the same need as every program that reads bytes that represent text. For a Python interpreter to read a source file, it must first determine its character encoding. Then it restarts and feeds decoded characters into a token lexer and syntax parser.

So, "interpreter", which is a program, just like "browser" or "validator". Or, with reference to Python project documentation, "[encoding detection algorithm in the tokenizer](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#concepts)".